# Windows batch file commands not executing

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Selenium tests using Docker with Selenium grid for which I am executing a batch file which is present in `src\test\resources` folder.

**Below is the content of the batch file:**

```
cd "%cd%\src\test\resources"
docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up -d
```

**Below is the Java code in BeforeSuite method:**

```
String gridFilePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\start_docker_grid.bat").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("absolutePath: " + gridFilePath);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"" + gridFilePath + "\"");
```

It opens the command prompt window but none of the commands in the batch file are executed.

[image]

Can anyone please help here ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243978/discussion-on-question-by-sandesh-sawant-windows-batch-file-commands-not-executi).